# Wordpress GCP click to deploy site address https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-cloud-platform, https

My Wordpress click to deploy on GCP has changed the site address from http:// to https:// during a settings change.

Currently there is no SSL certificate attached to the VM. Any idea how to change the site address and admin address back to http:// so the link is clickable?

I added a new SSL certificate when trying to move the domain name, but encountered an error and it's since changed to https://, but there is no SSL certificate for the static IP

Comment: There are several locations where this is can set: wp-config.php, the Apache site configuration files, and links in MySQL. Google search for tutorials on how to configure Apache and set up WordPress. Edit your question with your configuration files. Tip: this question should be posted here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are certain top-level domains, .dev for example, that automatically redirect from HTTP to HTTPS and you cannot change that action. I recommend that you first configure an SSL certificate as you will need that almost immediately. Each time you log into WordPress, your user and password are sent over the Internet in the clear.

Comment: Great, that's helpful. I'll have a look in the Apache config, thanks!